# how to remove a button dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#

i have added a `button` and number of `textBox` dynamically in my C# winform app. how can i remove them dynamically? specially if i have number of same controls?

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to search for a control you made dynamically? removing is straight forward enough how ever as others have said.

Comment: @Salman, read some books then start programming, or at least google your problem.

Comment: @ BeemerGuy: i accept when it is helpful so strange that you are commenting like this!

Comment: @Saeed: Do you have the answer?? then provide it! and thanks for the advice i'll consider it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the reference from the `Controls` collection that holds them.

```
frm.Controls.Remove(button1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `someContainer.Controls.Remove(someControl)`.

Alternatively, you can just `Dispose()` the control.